# How to add chrome extension thumbnail image to be displayed in webstore?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, manifest.json

I find other chrome extensions are displaying full width thumbnails in chrome web store, but mine is showing only a small blurred icon. Where can I update the image ? Is there something in manifest json I am missing ?

My manifest json has following icon

```
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "img/icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into your Chrome webstore developer account and select your extension listing.

In the section "Promotional tile images", upload images for the **Small tile, Large tile** and **Marquee**. Then press "Publish changes" at the bottom of the page.

You can click "Preview my promotional tiles" to see the result before publishing.

If the images don't appear in the store within a couple of hours, it may be so that they were denied in the reviewing process that the Chrome store team carry out. You won't get any notifications for this - so read through the guidelines thoroughly. [Read the guidelines here.](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/images#promo)

Comment: I have already uploaded those three but still I see only one icon.

Comment: Even when you click "Preview my promotional tiles"? I think it may take some time before the change is visible in the store.

Comment: @HariDas did it appear in the store?

Comment: No, its still the same.

Comment: Try pressing "Publish changes" at the bottom of the page after you uploaded the pictures

Comment: Actually I uploaded them since very beginning before I asked this question here. So they already published.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161031/discussion-between-hari-das-and-maxpaj).